# HTML5 page 100% height Issue

Tags: css, html, height

I am trying to create a App page which will auto fit to the height. following in the HTML code used in the page

```
<div id="main" role="main">
<header class="header">
    <div class="allPageHeaderImg"></div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo-viva.png" alt="VIVAGREL Logo" /></div>
</header>
<section class="allContent">
    <div class="button-links-subpg">
        <ul class="buttons">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/graceButton.png" alt="cardiac-button" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/timiButton.png" alt="cardiac-button" /></a></li>      
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
<footer id="footer">
    <div id="footerBg">
        <div class="footer-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Back</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
```

The CSS used

```
html {
  height:100%!important;
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%!important;
}

#main {
  height:100%;
  margin:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  background:#fff;
}

.header {
  height:145px;
  width:100%;
  background:url(../images/header-repbg-320.png) left top repeat-x;
  display:block;
  display:inline-block;
}

.allContent {
  width:100%;
  border:0 solid green;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:block;
  display:inline-block;
}

#footer {
  background:url(../images/footer-repbg-320.png) bottom left repeat-x;
  height:90px;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

My problem is, the whole page is only consuming half of the height of the page leaving a awkward space below footer,

Question: How to make the contents auto fit itself to the height of the page?

Comment: Look at this link: http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem using your code. But try this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: Can you use JS ? , Set min-height in pixel with device height, Just that !

Comment: A Webpage is virtually infinite, so how can you have 100% of infinity? Rather, use an absolute height in pixels, or use one of the creative methods below.

Answer (score 1):

[Click for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GGGTb/3/)
Set Html and body tag `height:100%;` and  you can give `maring:0;` and 
`padding :0;` to body tag also 
just give wrapper div  `height:100%;`

### HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">  
<div id="header">
    header
</div>     
<div id="content">
    content
</div> 
 <div id="footer">
    footer
</div>  
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

### Css

```
html{
    height: 100%;

}
body{
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    height: 100%;
}
#Wrapper{
        text-align:center;
        margin: auto;
     height:100%;

    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
    background-color:orange;

}
#header{
    height:10%;
   background-color:yellow; 
}
#content{
    height:80%;
   background-color:#4072b4; 
}
#footer{
    height:10%;
   background-color:green; 
}
```

[image: Output]

---

With out setting padding to body and html tag background image will not work

### [Not working example](http://jsfiddle.net/h5VXS/) and [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h5VXS/3/)

[Your question's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGGTb/5/)

[image: Your example with background image]

### And its output, It works fine on browser resizing

Comment: What about header and footer ?

Comment: @l2aelba now with header and footer

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. I simply revised the CSS of the first three selectors as follows:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 960px;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

I only added the background, width and borders to the #main selector to show it working. It will work without those properties however the margin and min-height are necessary. You will also notice how the !important value is unnecessary and as a best practice should be used mainly for troubleshooting conflicts with inheritance.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#main {

    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;

}

.header {

    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:145px;
    width:100%;
    background:url(../images/header-repbg-320.png) left top repeat-x;
    display:block;
    display:inline-block;

}

.allContent {

    position: absolute;
    top:145px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:90px;
    width:100%;
    border:0 solid green;
    display:block;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;

}

#footer {

    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    background:url(../images/footer-repbg-320.png) bottom left repeat-x;
    height:90px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    display:inline-block;

}
```