# Set the correct height dimension of a three-row-layout

Tags: html, css

How can I create three rows with the following height:

1. The header should be 70px
2. Main should be 30% of the screen
3. Footer should be taking the rest of the space

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
main {
  background-color: green;
  height: 30%;
  position: relative;
}
footer {
  background-color: #ddd;
  /* height? */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202427/make-footer-take-remianing-bottom-space-using-css

Comment: @resolute_coder – That question is WAY out of date.  I'd say this warrants a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
width: calc(70% - 70px);
```

on the footer, see browser support here
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc